# FOL: variable assignment and x-variant

Tags: logic

Someone can explain me in poor words why we need an x-variant when we deal with the interpretation of quantified formula?

Let s be the value assignment and v the x-variant.

For example M \models_s \forall x A iff M \models_v A for every assignment v that agree with s except possibly at the variable x.

I understand how it works, but i dont catch why we need a second assignment, may we have said "for every assignment s" insteand of "for every assignment v that agree with s"?

And what does it mean "that agree with s except possibly at the variable x"?

Comment: "what does it mean 'that agree with s except possibly at the variable xi'?" Let the variables: x1,x2,..., xi,... It means that v1(xn)=v2(xn) for every n **except** (maybe) for xn=xi.

Comment: See e.g. [Connection between interpretation, variable assignment and truth valuation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2339624/connection-between-interpretation-variable-assignment-and-truth-valuation) and [Variable Assignments](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1237532/logic-variable-assignments).